# Different properties interpreting of some constant object in WPF

Tags: wpf, design-patterns

I have a data packet, that body is consist of byte array. Also I need interprete a packet fields in few variations, but the body is still constant. For example:
*AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF* - constant packet's body.
In first interpretation: *AA-BB-CC* - as a Parameter 1 and *DD-EE-FF* - as a Parameter 2.
In second variation: *AA-BB* - as a Parameter 3, *CC-DD* - Parameter 4, and *EE-FF* - Parameter 5.
And so on.

I see few options to realize such behavior:

1. In single class create all of the needed properties (parameter 1...parameter 5), and in caller class check the variation flag.
2. Create few derived classes, and each class contains only specific properties (parameters 1 and 2 in first case, parameters from 3 to 5 - in the second).

Now to show packets in WPF I use 1st option. I have ListView and it's style as GridView:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" />
```

When I need to visualize packets in first interpretation:

```
lv.Style = CType(TryFindResource("packetsStyle_1"), Style)
```

The *packetsStyle_1* contains columns "Parameter 1" and "Parameter 2".

When I need to visualize packets in other interpretation, I just change the style of ListView:

```
lv.Style = CType(TryFindResource("packetsStyle_2"), Style)
```

The *packetsStyle_2* contains columns "Parameter 3", "Parameter 4" and "Parameter 5".

This kind of realization is not object-oriented, as I understand. I want to do this with the OOP (option 2) - base class of packet with common properties and inherited classes with specific properties. But what is the WPF way to refresh GUI in this case?
Do I need create two objects List(of PacketVar1) and List(of PacketVar2) and change ListView item's source and style? But list of packets is huge enough, and takes a lot of memory. Or what is the right implementation?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like a flags enum to determine type? and then use that type to base the class on?

Comment: @KevinCook yes, exactly. But if use OOP, so enum should be redundant.